# Huion H58L click event breaks and re-clicks while touch and drag

Tags: windows-10, graphics-tablet

Hey There I have a new Huionn H58L graphics tablet. The problem could be a factory defect but could also be a software or optional problem thats why i wanted to ask. As you know in the hover type tablets, when you touch the tablet with pen, it is simulating a click event and as long as you hold it touched and move, its dragging until you lift the pen and it drops. My problem is; when i touch it clicks but when i start dragging it is dropping even if my hand is still on the tablet. This is making me unable to use Photoshop selects, curves, level sliders etc. because it breaks the click and reclicks which causes uncontrollable behaviours.

Do you have any idea about this? Any solution? Can it be fixed by a techinician if it's a hardware problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I have found the solution for this problem. Actually, the solution was a simple one but there was not any information on the internet, even i got in touch with Huion, they are not aware of the problem. The problem is the driver for windows. I don't know about other version of the windows but if you are using windows 10 then probably you will face with this problem and the solution is removing all the drivers of the tablet with all components and files then restart and download the oldest driver (versipn 11.1.0) from the link below and install it. Thats it.

https://www.huion.com/download/type-1/?Keyword=h58l